# Как получить список файлов в директории? (Android API Level 26)

Tags: java, android, файлы, io, permissions

Каким образом можно получить список файлов в директории?

Я добавил в **AndroidManifest.xml** разрешения:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Пытаюсь получить список файлов:

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).getPath());
File f = new File(dir.toString());
File[] list = f.listFiles(); // Получаю null, хотя файлы и папки там есть
```

Сама же директория, при этом, возвращает `true` на проверки [`.isDirectory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#isDirectory()) и [`.exists()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#exists()).

При попытке сделать то же самое через NIO получаю [`AccessDeniedException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/AccessDeniedException.html).

Comment: в рантайме запрашиваете пермишены ?

Comment: @LexHobbit , нет. Спасибо, по всей видимости в этом и проблема. Оформите ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865206/accessing-getexternalstoragedirectory

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего вы не запрашиваете разрешения в runtime...

Для запроса разрешений в runtime используйте следующий код:

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        // Explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
    }

    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
    // app-defined int constant that should be quite unique

    return;
}
```

Код для обработки запроса на разрешения:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

источник - https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

**Важно:** До *Android 8.0* (**API 26**), если приложение запрашивало разрешение во время выполнения и разрешение было предоставлено, система также неправильно предоставляла приложению остальные разрешения, принадлежащие той же группе разрешений, которые были зарегистрированы в манифесте.

В *Android 8.0*, это поведение было исправлено. Приложение получает только разрешения, которые были запрошенны явно. Однако, как только пользователь предоставляет разрешение приложению, все последующие запросы на разрешения, относящиеся к той же группе разрешений, предоставляются автоматически.