# Работа с файлами Android

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь в программирование на андроид, нужно сделать перебор файлов в папке
Ввожу следующий код:

```
File DirPhone = new File("/sdcard/pictures/");
File[] arrPics = DirPhone.listFiles();
```

В папке точно есть файл, но массив arrPics = null
пробовал и просто на "/sdcard/", и на "/storage/emulated/0/" смотреть, всегда массив файлов возвращается null. Разрешения дал:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

что я делаю не так?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить список файлов в директории? (Android API Level 26)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/741673/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8-android-api-level-26)

Answer (score 0):

1. Путь нужно указывать полностью (включая пусть сд-карты).
2. Добавить разрешения в манифест != получить их. Эти разрешения ещё нужно запросить у пользователя.
3. Смотрите, что пишет в логе.

Comment: 1. Попробовал через new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/picturesagentplus/");

Comment: всё равно listFile() = null

Comment: @myax, читаем ещё раз пункт 2 и смотрим этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/741691/11515