# Подскажите пожалуйста причину AccessDeniedException

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, исключения

Здраствуйте! Пытаюсь воспользоваться методом `Files.readAllLines`, но получаю исключение `AccessDeniedException`

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Path directory = Paths.get("D:\\it\\A");

        boolean isDirectory = Files.isDirectory(directory);
        boolean isWritable = Files.isWritable(directory);
        System.out.println(isDirectory);
        System.out.println(isWritable);
        List<String>list = new ArrayList<>();
        list=Files.readAllLines(directory);

    }
}
```

Консоль:

```
true
true
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: D:\it\A
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:89)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:236)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:380)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:432)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:422)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:160)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Files.java:2923)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Files.java:3413)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Files.java:3454)
    at Test.main(Test.java:20)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Пробовал на разных локальных дисках создавать папку, папка действительно существует по этому адресу, режим "Только для чтения" выключен как для данной папки, так и для всех вложенных. Антивирус отключен, другое приложение папку не использует. Интернет перерыл, но ответ так и не нашел. ОС Windows 10 PRO, среда разработки:

> IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1 (Community Edition) Build #IC-221.5080.210, built
> on April 12, 2022 Runtime version: 11.0.14.1+1-b2043.25 amd64

Понимаю, что наверняка ошибка какая-то глупая, но ответ найти не могу. Заранее благодарен за помощь!

`InputStream`:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String path = "D:\\it\\A\\A2\\TEXT1.txt";

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(path);
        int a=0;
        while ((a=is.read())!=-1) {
           System.out.println((char)a);
        }
        is.close();
 }
}
```

Также работает `Files.readAllBytes`:

```
 public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            String path = "D:\\it\\A\\A2\\TEXT1.txt";
    
            String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));
            System.out.println(content);
     }

}
```

UPD. проверил через `cmd`
данная папка установлены разрешения на чтение и запись.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25349182/java-nio-file-accessdeniedexception-when-reading-a-file Пробовали сделать через InputStream прочитать файл?

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/741673/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8-android-api-level-26

Comment: InputStream читает. Добавил листинг в вопрос

Comment: fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(myFile.toPath()); из вашей ссылки также проходит без проблем. Даже без условий ветви if. Проблема только с методом readAllLines

Comment: Добавил ответ. Попробуйте через readline. Протестировал у себя - работает. Если не поможет, стоит попробовать запустить от администратора программу. Может сама система не даёт прочитать файл

Comment: Ваши оба способа работают, я могу прочитать файл в данной директории. Но вот получить лист с содержимым директории не удается. Запускал программу от адинистратора. Ноут перезагружал. Не помогло (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взято с https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/how-to-read-all-files-in-a-folder-from-java

```
public void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
        } else {
            System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
        }
    }
}

final File folder = new File("/home/you/Desktop");
listFilesForFolder(folder);
```

или (Java 8+)

```
try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get("/home/you/Desktop"))) {
    paths
        .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Это все работает, файлы я могу прочитать без проблем всеми известными способами. А вот  список объектов в директории, я не могу получить

Comment: @had0uken Исправил ответ. Не видел, что вам нужно не файл прочитать, а найти файлы из директории. Если этот ответ не поможет, посмотрите в приложенной выше ссылке другие варианты

Comment: Спасибо! Второй вариант как раз то что нужно.  Но почему не сработал readAllLines я так и не пойму (

Comment: ReadAllLines читает строки из файла, а не из папки. Даже в документации об этом написано https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

Comment: Точно!!! Вот и ответ!!! Я где-то либо не там смотрел, либо не так описание метода прочитал и несколько часов его неадекватно пытался использовать, негодуя почему не работает )) Видать перегрелся!! Спасибо!!!! Так и знал, что ошибка какая-то глупая... Так и вышло